# SwiftUI: Have a button change itself?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a struct that shows a menu of radio buttons.

The issue I have is the following: when I press a button, I want the Text(item) View to change color. I'm not sure how to do that, since the Text(item) is encompassed by the button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RadioMenu: View {

    var items = [String]()
    @State var isChecked: Bool = false
    @State var selection: String? = nil
    var textSize: Int = 20

    init(items: [String], textSize: Int) {
        self.items = items
        self.textSize = textSize
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                Button (action: {
                    self.isChecked = true
                    self.selection = item

                }) {
                    Text(item)
                        .font(.system(size: CGFloat(self.textSize), weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                    )}
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this modifier on `Text` :

```
.foregroundColor(item == self.selection ? Color.red : Color.black)
```